# Is multiple #define possible?

Tags: c, gcc, cortex-m

I have build two applications, both working fine.
Using GCC C compiler. Target: LPC40xx MCU.

Problem:
The author of the two libraries has used different values for the same register.
When I try to compile, I get tons of "Multiple defines".

Example:

```
file1.h: #define DEF1 1
file2.h: #define DEF1 0x0001

file1.c include file1.h (DEF1 = 1)
file2.c include file2.h (DEF1 = 0x0001)
```

Even though they technically has the same value, the linker does not like it.

Whar I want, is to tell the compiler/linker to ignore that there are a multiple definition.
file1.c includes file1.h with the "#define DEF1 1", and should ignore that file2.h has another definition of DEF1, but just go for the DEV1 definition in the file it includes.

file1.c

```
- include file1.h
- #define DEV1 1
```

file2.c

```
- include file2.h
- #define DEV1 0x0001
```

What I search for, is a way to force file1.c to use the #define in the .h file it includes, and ignore the #define in other .h files.

is this possible in any way?

Comment: You could have a "fixer" include file that repairs this somehow by `#undef DEF1` and then redefine properly.

Comment: Your question lacks some [MCVE]. We can only *guess* what you really want

Comment: I don't think the linker cares anything about `#define`s. Are you sure the `#define`s are the real problem?

Comment: You have omitted critical information. As you have shown it, `file1.c` includes `file1.h` and not `file2.h`, and `file2.c` includes `file2.h` and not `file1.h`. And each of the header files defines only a preprocessor symbol. This will not cause multiple definition errors in either the compiler or the linker. As Basile Starynkevitch notes, you should provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The main application includes both .h files, to get access to different function calls. And then the compiler sees the multiple defs. 
I could try to see if it is possible to avoid this, but I don't think it is easy

Comment: If both headers are provided by the same library and are meant to be included in the same source file, the difference in the two definitions is a bug. The compiler is required to allow 'benign redefinition' of a macro where the replacement sequences are token-for-token the same, but otherwise is required to issue a diagnostic. The library should choose decimal or hex and stick with it. Even better, it shouldn't define the same macro in two different headers — if only one header defines it, there isn't a problem in the first place. I regard this as a bug in the library — I think you should too.

Comment: See C11 [§6.10.3 Macro replacement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3) ¶1,2 for more on 'identical replacement lists'.

Comment: The problem arises because the two projects uses two different implementations of the library. So I have to act as it is two different libraries.
But because they implement the "same" functionality, the same names are often used.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. As @tadman pointed out, you could just `#undef DEV1` in between `#include`
2. Edit the sources

The warning is very important since otherwise, an overridden header could be catastrophic. In your case, since their values are the same, it won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that file1 and file2 are separate modules that should be kept apart, standard practice in C is to prefix the name of the #define with some short namespace for the logical unit e.g.:

```
#define FILE1_DEF1 1
```

You should be doing this for function names in header files too in order to avoid collisions. Look at the SDL graphics programming library for a really good example (in my opinion).

If file1 and file2 are both sub-components of some overarching module then you should abstract the definition of DEF1 to some other header file which both file1.h and file2.h can include.

Comment: Yes, and that is how i normally would do it.
But in this case, i am working with two different 3rd party implementations of the "same" library functions. 
There are several hundreds of defines, to define everything from register addresses, typedefs etc.

Comment: Ah! Never mind then. I didn't realise the scale of the project.

Answer (score 0):

so this is common is sdk headers, generally they will just undef whatever the symbol is before they define it:

example from complex.h:

```
#undef complex
#define complex _Complex
#undef _Complex_I
/*  Constant expression of type const float _Complex                          */
#define _Complex_I (__extension__ 1.0iF)
#undef I
#define I _Complex_I
```

This usually works pretty well, but if you have conflicting names that work differently then you may have to get more creative.

Comment: The problem is that the two libararies has several hundreds of defines, typedefs etc.
This task would be quite time consuming.
And what if the vendor of the libraries changes the source?
Then i can't just copy the new source directly.

Comment: @Kaare the compiler can't figure out what symbol would be expanded, it isn't possible; you you need to undef them if they exist in both places... preprocessor directives dont have scope, they are lexically expanded. If they are just values you can use things like `static const int dog = 5;` then they dont leak out of the compilation unit

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the `-DDEV1=0x0001` option to the `gcc` compiler when compiling `file2.c`.

Then you probably want to code in `file1.h` something like

```
#ifndef DEV1
#define DEV1 1
#endif
```

Read more about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Read also the [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

PS. I am not sure to understand what you exactly want to achieve. However, I believe you do want to pass some `-D` flag in some of your compilations and you might also need `#ifndef`

Comment: I want to merge two different projects, each using different implementations of the "same" MCU library.
The libraries / CMSIS files are written by two different vendors, and they did not agree on naming conventions...
Now I am looking for a simple, general way to keep the access to the two libraries appart, and not generate the multiple defines warnings.